# Python Best Practices: Pass to Method or Instance Variable

Tags: python

In Python, should I be writing my methods like option 1 or option 2 in the code below? Thanks!

```
from someHardware import someHardware

# Option 1, pass the data into method
class SomeClass:

    def getValue( self ):
        rawData = someHardware.getData()
        return self.calculateValue( rawData )

    def calculateValue( self, rawData ):
        return ( rawData * 100 ) - 5

# Option 2, save data as instance variable
class SomeClass:

    def getValue( self ):
        self.rawData = someHardware.getData()
        return self.calculateValue()

    def calculateValue( self ):
        return ( self.rawData * 100 ) - 5
```

Comment: This is more of an "opinion" question, so it may have to be closed. But my personal opinion is - there is no reason to use a class if you do option 1. Option 1 is functional programming, while Option 2 is OOP.

Comment: I think the answer to your question depends quite a bit on other information. Does the value returned by `someHarware.getData()` change over time? Is it slow to be fetched, so that we should cache it, even if it might change after a while? As for the design question, you might also consider using a `property`, rather than an explicit `getValue` function.

Answer (score 1):

If your method is called `calculateValue`, definitively give it something to calculate on, that's semantically clearer. Also, that method is public (no `_` to mark it as not-API), so it should make sense to call it externally.

Also, if you do that, your `calculateValue` will be independent from `self`, making it basically a `staticmethod`, thus:

```
class SomeClass:

    def getValue( self ):
        rawData = someHardware.getData()
        return self.calculateValue( rawData )

    @staticmethod
    def calculateValue( rawData ):
        return ( rawData * 100 ) - 5
```

Will make it clearer.